# How do I fix amdgpu and amdgpu-dkms packages not installing?

Tags: linux, apt, linux-kernel, drivers, gpu

I'm trying to install the amdgpu package and it throws a bunch of errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dctrl-tools dh-dkms libcfitsio9 libgdal31 libmpdec3 libnginx-mod-http-geoip libnginx-mod-http-image-filter libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream libnginx-mod-stream-geoip
  libpoppler123 libprotobuf23 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libtiff5 libzxingcore1 linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-common linux-kbuild-6.1 nginx-common nginx-core
  python-pastedeploy-tpl python3-commonmark python3-speaklater python3.10 python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal ruby3.0 ruby3.0-dev ruby3.0-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu amdgpu-dkms
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/9,848 kB of archives.
After this operation, 428 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-dkms.
(Reading database ... 503090 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-dkms_1%3a5.18.13.50403-1538762.22.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms (1:5.18.13.50403-1538762.22.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu_1%3a5.4.50403-1538762.22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu (1:5.4.50403-1538762.22.04) ...
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.18.13.50403-1538762.22.04) ...
Loading new amdgpu-5.18.13-1538762.22.04 DKMS files...
Building for 6.0.0-kali6-amd64
Building for architecture amd64
Building initial module for 6.0.0-kali6-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.0-kali6-amd64 (amd64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms; however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyways, I tried reinstalling them and it doesn't work. Not after apt purge, or apt upgrade. I'm kind of lost. I read `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/make.log` logs and it looks like the problem is that it's trying to install the packages for `6.0.1-kali5-amd64` instead of `6.0.0-kali6-amd64`. I don't know how to fix it tho. This started happening after i updated my system. The new kernel kept throwing 'kernel panic - not syncing' so I uninstalled it. It looks like apt thinks the old kernel is still installed. Here are the logs if this can help:

```
DKMS make.log for amdgpu-5.18.13-1538762.22.04 for kernel 6.0.0-kali6-amd64 (amd64)
Thu Apr  6 09:08:53 PM CEST 2023
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-amd64'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/scheduler/sched_main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_tt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/symbols.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_common.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu.h:69,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/backport/include/kcl/kcl_amdgpu_drm_fb_helper.h:35,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/backport/backport.h:84,
                 from <command-line>:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_mode.h:308:32: error: field ‘base’ has incomplete type
  308 |         struct drm_framebuffer base;
      |                                ^~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/backport/backport.h:85:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/backport/include/kcl/kcl_amdgpu_drm_gem_framebuffer_helper.h: In function ‘kcl_drm_gem_fb_set_obj’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/backport/include/kcl/kcl_amdgpu_drm_gem_framebuffer_helper.h:12:19: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct drm_framebuffer’
   12 |                 fb->obj[index] = obj;
      |                   ^~
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/scripts/Makefile.build:254: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/scripts/Makefile.build:470: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/scheduler/sched_fence.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_kernel_params.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/dma-buf/dma-resv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/scheduler/sched_entity.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_backlight.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_ioctl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo_util.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/scheduler/amd-sched.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_bo_vm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_kthread.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_perf_event.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_seq_file.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_suspend.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_pci.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_module.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_execbuf_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_memory.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_range_manager.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_sched.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_resource.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence_array.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_pool.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_reservation.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_cache.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_auth.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_pool.c: In function ‘ttm_pool_mgr_init’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_pool.c:726:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘register_shrinker’
  726 |         return register_shrinker(&mm_shrinker);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/include/linux/mm.h:20,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/include/linux/scatterlist.h:8,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/include/linux/dma-mapping.h:10,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/include/kcl/kcl_dma_mapping.h:5,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/backport/backport.h:9,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/include/linux/shrinker.h:99:27: note: declared here
   99 | extern int __printf(2, 3) register_shrinker(struct shrinker *shrinker,
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_pool.c:727:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
  727 | }
      | ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/scripts/Makefile.build:254: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm/ttm_pool.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_fb.o
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/scripts/Makefile.build:470: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/ttm] Error 2
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_print.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fbmem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_crtc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_connector.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_atomic_helper.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_device_cgroup.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mn.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_modes.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_time.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_ftrace.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_acpi_table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_page_alloc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_numa.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fs_read_write.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_aperture.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_simple_kms_helper.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_bitmap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_vmscan.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_dma_fence_chain.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mce_amd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_workqueue.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_cpumask.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_cpumask.c:6:1: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]
    6 | /**
      |  
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_dsc_helper.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_debugfs_inode.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_sysfs_emit.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build/amd/amdkcl/amdkcl.o
make: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-common/Makefile:1876: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1538762.22.04/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-kali6-amd64'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Kali is not intended as a general purpose OS. Do not attempt to use it as one, unless you understand the implications.

Comment: @vidarlo yes, i am trying to install amdgpu drivers on it because hashcat doesn't detect my gpu at all. i wouldn't want the gpu to just sit there and collect dust.

Comment: `it's trying to install the packages for 6.0.1-kali5-amd64 instead of 6.0.0-kali6-amd64` - nothing you've posted indicates that is the case - the term `6.0.1-kali5-amd64` appears once in your post where you incorrectly assume the problem, where as `6.0.0-kali6-amd64` appears over a dozen times - I assume `6.0.1-kali5-amd64` is the kernel that panics and was uninstalled?

Comment: Where does the amdgpu package come from? Is this the official AMD package or the one provided by Kali's repositories?

Comment: @Mach Run hashcat on a distro that is actually intended for general use, e.g. Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, Fedora or similar.

Comment: @vidarlo Ok, well i like how kali has everything i need preinstalled, would you recommend dual boot or virtual machine?

Comment: I'd generally suggest VM.